# Can I keep reference to Friends Pictures?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, photo-gallery

Can I use friends pictures from their gallery after getting permission 
in my application?

Not download them just keep a link/reference to selected photos 
using Facebook graph API and PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can - hopefully you will not do anything nasty with them :P  You should make it clear to your users what your intentions are and how you plan to use their photos and for what.

Comment: thanks for the replay can you please give hint on how i do that ?

Comment: hint : [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) - you are looking for the `picture` connection - gotta scroll down a bit to see it... :P

Comment: Hi , well there is the album connection , but how can i get selected picture from selected album ?

Comment: Have you looked at the graph API documentation? All the information you need is there - if you have a specific problem i'll be happy to help but you'll have to do some research on your own - we are not going to do the work for you.  You'll find all the information at [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Comment: man sure i did search , again . only albums i found how to get not pictures

Comment: once you have the `album_id`  you make a call to `https://graph.facebook.com/album_id` and you'll get a list of photo id's, then you make a call to `https://graph.facebook.com/album_id/photo_id` and you'll find the pictures information there.

Comment: if you want to STORE the pictures, you have to tell the user exactly why and how he can contact you to delete them whenever he wants. if you just want to keep a reference in form of the photo id, that´s fine. but keep in mind that you cannot read the photos later without an access token of the user who owns it.